# Is possible to blacklist the height property from img tag only

Tags: stylelint

I want to blacklist the height property for all img selectors in the stylesheet, so the aspect ratio of the image is always respected, is it possible with stylelint?

Answer (score 0):

It isn't possible to do this with confidence as stylelint only analyses your CSS code and doesn't understand your HTML structure.

However, it is possible to [create a plugin](https://github.com/stylelint/stylelint/blob/master/docs/developer-guide/plugins.md) that disallows the `height` property for the `img` type selector. This could catch some instances. The plugin could be called `stylelint-rule-selector-property-blacklist`. For example:

```
"plugin/rule-selector-property-blacklist": { "img": ["height"] }
```

You can use the built-in [`declaration-property-value-blacklist`](https://github.com/stylelint/stylelint/tree/master/lib/rules/declaration-property-value-blacklist) rule as a blueprint for the plugin.

But this wouldn't catch instances where a image is targeted by another means, though. For example:

```
<p><img class="can-be-anything" src="my-image.jpg" /></p>

/* target via class name */
.can-be-anything { height: 10px; }

/* target via universal selector */
p > * { height: 10px }
```